# How can i replace numerical value (version) using MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, database, replace, phpmyadmin

I am building a Document versioning intranet website. I have around 1700 book title names which includes version like

- Book for Dummies 1.2
- Testbook HTML5 Class 3.5.7 students
- Learning Amazon S3 Deployment 1.3.4.3 writings

How can i remove document version x.x.x or x.x from all the document title names.

As i want to publish a list of all Title without version names on front page.

I tried **REPLACE** function in MYSQL replacing dots, but it also replaced 3 in S3 and 5 in HTML5.

```
update book_title_all set title=REGEXP_REPLACE(title,'[0-9]','')
update book_title_all set title=REPLACE(title,'.','')
```

**I want that only numerical string in the format x.x.x / x.x only be replaced.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8+, then the `REGEXP_REPLACE` function comes in handy here:

```
UPDATE book_title_all
SET title = TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(title, '\s*[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)+\s*', ' '))
WHERE title REGEXP '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+';
```

The idea here is to replace every version string `1.2.3.4`, along with optional whitespace surrounding it, with just a single space.  This keeps the formatting of the title clean after the replacement.  Note that this creates an edge case, where a version string appears at the very beginning or end of the title.  In this case, our replacement would leave an extra space.  The call to `TRIM()` is needed to remove this.